# Writing multiple values in a text file using python

Tags: python

I want to write mulitiple values in a text file using python.

I wrote the following line in my code:

```
text_file.write("sA" + str(chart_count) + ".Name = " + str(State_name.groups())[2:-3] + "\n")
```

Note: `State_name.groups()` is a regex captured word. So it is captured as a `tuple` and to remove the `(` `)` brackets from the `tuple` I have used string slicing.

Now the output comes as:

```
sA0.Name = GLASS_OPEN
```

No problem here

But I want the output to be like this:

```
sA0.Name = 'GLASS_HATCH_OPENED_PROTECTION_FCT'
```

I want the variable value to be enclosed inside the single quotes.

Comment: you should really clarify what you mean. After reading your post three time I still do not understand what you want to do. Also your code example is not a "working example" as it contains variables that are not defined in the example, nobody but you can test it and improve it.

Comment: If your question is simply how to add single quotes in a string: you can use them as other characters in a python string. Just make sure you delimit your string with double quotes. So `"sA0.Name = " + "'" + "GLASS_OPEN" + "'"` yields `sA0.Name = 'GLASS_OPEN'`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
text_file.write("sA" + str(chart_count) + ".Name = '" + str(State_name.groups())[2:-3] + "'\n")
#                                                  ^single quote here             and here^
```